# Lower bound for $k$-systole on $T^{2k}$ using Euclidean metric

Tags: systolic-geometry

Consider the torus ${\mathbb T}^{2k}={\mathbb R}^{2k}/\Lambda$, where $\Lambda$ is a lattice.  I am looking for a lower bound on the volume using the Euclidean metric of a cycle that represents a nontrivial $k$-th homology class using ${\mathbb Z}_2$ coefficients.  I would like this lower bound in terms of certain properties of the lattice (the so-called Rankin invariant and the volume of the torus).  I will give the precise conjecture at the end of this question.  The motivation for the question comes from a problem in quantum coding theory; see http://arxiv.org/abs/1608.05089   Even a very weak lower bound would suffice (I would be happy with a bound up to factors which are exponential in the dimension $k$) and if the conjecture below holds, it would lead to a large improvement in the best known parameters for certain quantum codes.  However, while the motivation is from coding theory, the conjecture can be expressed without any knowledge of quantum codes.

Let me first consider the case of integer coefficients.  If the given homology class can be represented by a $k$-dimensional hyperplane, then it is possible to prove using calibrations that such a hyperplane has least volume among all cycles representing that homology class.  Such a hyperplane is represented by a $k$-tuple of vectors, $v_1,\ldots,v_k \in \Lambda$, and the volume of the cycle is given by ${\rm det}(S^\dagger S)^{1/2}$, where $S$ is a $2k$-by-$k$ matrix whose columns are the vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_k$.  We write this volume as ${\rm vol}(v_1,\ldots,v_k)$.  The minimum
$$(*) \quad {\rm min}_{v_1,\ldots,v_k \in \Lambda, {\rm vol}(v_1,\ldots,v_k)\neq 0} {\rm vol}(v_1,\ldots,v_k)$$
is closely related to the so-called Rankin invariant of the lattice (take this minimum, divide it by the square-root of the volume of the lattice, and square the result, and this is the Rankin invariant $\gamma_{2k,k}$).

However, for other homology classes using integer coefficients, those which cannot be represented by a single hyperplane but can only be represented by a sum of hyperplanes (the classes that can be represented by sums of hyperplanes correspond to split $k$-vectors), I do not see how to obtain a nontrivial lower bound, and it is not obvious to me whether or not the least volume cycle might have volume much smaller than the least volume hyperplane.  I am searching for a lower bound that would express how much smaller the least volume can be, and I would like this lower bound in the ${\mathbb Z}_2$ case.

The conjecture I would like to prove is: there is a constant $C>0$, such that for any $k$, and any $\Lambda$, the least volume ${\mathbb Z}_2$ cycle representing a nontrivial $k$-th homology class has volume which is at least $C^k$ times the volume of the least volume hyperplane with nonzero volume, i.e., it is at least $C^k$ times the minimum (*) above.  I would be happy to have this result in the special case that $\Lambda$ is an integral lattice and the cycle is restricted to a cubulation of the torus ${\mathbb R}^{2k}/\Lambda$ by unit hypercubes.

Comment: Try asking Victor Bangert or Ivan Babenko (although this is a bit more geometry of numbers than systolic geometry since your metric is flat).

Comment: You might consider adding a top-level tag in order to make more people see this question.